# LinkedIn authentication in Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, oauth, windows-phone, linkedin-api

According to LinkedIn Developer Docs:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~ gives only first name,last name,header,url.

To request any fields beyond this limited set, we must use Field Selectors.

I want to get email also.

So in the below code, I made changes:

```
            var client = new RestClient
        {
            Authority = "https://api.linkedin.com",
            HasElevatedPermissions = true
        };

        var request = new RestRequest
        {
            Credentials = credentials,
            Path = "/v1/people/~",
            Method = WebMethod.Get
        };


        // https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address)

     client.BeginRequest(request, new RestCallback(CurrentUserProfileRequestCallback));
```

**Changes:**

```
 var request = new RestRequest
            {
                Credentials = credentials,
                Path = " /v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address)",
                Method = WebMethod.Get
            };
```

But, Its giving me **404: Page Not Found** in response stream.

Comment: What is the full request that you end up making (leaving out the access token)? Your example has a leading space before the /v1/people... portion of the path. Can you try removing that space?